# Better to send all data to client or query server for every search?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, optimization

I have a search function on my site that needs to search through ~2000 items (this table never changes, it will always have the same number of items) stored in MySQL. All it needs to do is search by name or 'LIKE' the name and return the id. I have thought of two approaches to this:

1. Query database using ajax on keyup(), this seems like it would be expensive with many people searching
2. Send all the data to client as a JSON file when they load the page and search through it using JavaScript to reduce the load on the database

Which approach is better? Or if you have a better approach I am open to suggestions.

Comment: if it's only 2000 items, offloading that to the client might save you a scalability headache in the future. It'll also reduce lag time for searches since there won't be any HTTP request latency.

Comment: Is an "item" one word?  Or a large document?

Comment: Will your `LIKE` have a leading wildcard?

Comment: @RickJames Each item is one word, and yes.

Comment: @obl - Consider `FULLTEXT INDEX`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your purpose. Do you want to provide search on fly functionality while user writes its search word or would like to return the result when the user clicks search button or something? Either way, you are talking about 2000 records which is not much actually. So I think you can store all those information into an offline memory cache and you can return your results from memory. SQL is also quite optimized for queries and it also caches the results so for 2000 records it shouldn't be any problem to perform the query to DB as well.